# Passing a Reusable rule id into an action

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

I would have like to use reusable execution Rules as an action but saw on a post that it is not supported by code effects. 
For example:  If Temperature is 54 then `RuleA`.
Is there any support for passing the ruleid into an action so it can be added to a collection of rule ids?

Example: IF Temperature is 54 THEN `PasseusableRuleId(reusableruleid)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Dynamic Menu Data Sources feature to create a list of your reusable rules and use that list as param in your action method. One small note to remember: dynamic menu sources can only use integers as IDs, so you cant just use GUID IDs of your rules in there. Instead, add a unique auto-incrementing int column to the rules table in your database and use those int values as IDs in dynamic menus. Details can be found at https://codeeffects.com/Doc/Business-Rules-Dynamic-Menu-Data-Sources